# Storing large responses from 3rd party API's as key val pairs or LONGTEXT?

Tags: mysql

Just as the title states, which is the best way to store the data?
If I do it in key/val pairs it will be *a lot* more rows but if I go with a JSON column or LONGTEXT and store the full raw response it will take up much more space.

The data stored doesn't have to be queried at all and we only want to store the raw response data from the 3rd party API.

This is the table structure at the moment:

[ id, request_id, response (LONGTEXT/JSON), created_at ]

[ 1, 312, "{data: ...}", 2018-01-01 20:00:00 ]

What is the best way to go about this? Keep it as is or do this with key value pairs instead?

Comment: You can store it in JSON format. Newer MySQL versions also support some interesting JSON based search/extract functions etc.

Comment: Yeah, that's totally possible. However, we don't need to query any of the keys within the response object itself, we just need to store its data. So, the only reason for us to switch to a JSON column type would be if it's less heavy than a LONGTEXT type. Is that the case?